# BlackBerry: How to use PersistableRIMKeyStore?

Tags: api, blackberry, keystore

I need to securely store private user data so it can persist across my app starts as well as device resets.

This will be a String I guess about 1000 chars at maximum.

I was told I can use RIM KeyStore API for this.

Well, I spent hours googling out any gide on RIM KeyStore API usage. JDE samples do not contain anything useful on this.

Looks like this is a rare thing in BB development, so there's almost no official info on this.

I read [this](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/crypto/keystore/package-summary.html) and [this](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/crypto/doc-files/Tutorial_KeyStore.html). From those I understood the best choice for me is to use PersistableRIMKeyStore (it persists across device resets). However I am not able to figure out what exactly should the implementation be.

Can anyone help with sample code or point me to some guide? Also maybe there's a better/simpler way/approach for my task, so, please, let me know about it.

Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Comment: The PersistableRIMKeyStore is used to persist the RIM Key Store. To persist user data accross resets you only need to use the PersistentStore, if you want the deta to be protected you could use the ContentProtectedHashtable or ContentProtectedVector

Comment: Richard, thanks a lot for your quick response! I will study your suggestion.

Comment: @Richard: Could you post your comment as an answer - I'm going to accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PersistableRIMKeyStore is used to persist the RIM Key Store. To persist user data accross resets you only need to use the PersistentStore, if you want the deta to be protected you could use the ContentProtectedHashtable or ContentProtectedVector.

Comment: Pointing me to the right direction (`PersistentStore` + `ContentProtectedHashtable`) was exaclty what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the store in the same was as the "PersistentStoreDemo" which if you don't know you can get by going to File -> Import -> Blackberry Samples, you can encrypt the info in the store. On top of this, if the user has content protection on, you can use a ContentProtectedHashtable to automatically know that that information would be encrypted. So, without content protection, the info would be encrypted once, with it on, it would be doubly encrypted as well as stored with a hard to guess long hash of the app namespace (obviously, since to register the store you need it). Below is what I use:

```
package ca.dftr.phillyd.lib.persistables;

import net.rim.device.api.system.ApplicationDescriptor;
import net.rim.device.api.util.ContentProtectedHashtable;
import net.rim.device.api.util.Persistable;

/**
 * Basic class for storing application specific information. 
 * Information such as application settings or whether the license agreement was accepted.
 * For more complex and specific classes they should be implemented separately and implement persistable 
 * @author deforbes
 */
public class AppInfo extends ContentProtectedHashtable  implements Persistable {

    private String _appName = null;
    private String _version = null;

    /**
     * Constructs the application info, creates and persists a hashtable for application settings.
     * @param uniqueHexAppIdentifier Can be automatically created in resource class (BUNDLE_ID) or generated using other unique information.
     */
    public AppInfo() {    
        ApplicationDescriptor appDesc = ApplicationDescriptor.currentApplicationDescriptor();
        _appName = appDesc.getName();
        _version = appDesc.getVersion();
    }

    /**
     * Get the Name of the application
     * @return The application name from the app descriptor
     */
    public String getName()
    {
        return _appName;
    }

    /**
     * Get the Version of the application
     * @return The application version from the app descriptor
     */
    public String getVersion()
    {
        return _version;
    }
}
```

Along with a class of constants (which could be included in the above if you want). For example, From my PhillyD app:

package ca.dftr.phillyd.lib.persistables;

```
/**
 * Keys for the AppInfo array
 * @author deforbes
 */
public class AppInfoKeys {
    public static final String QUALITY = "Quality";
    public static final String CHANNEL = "Channel";
    public static final String CHANNEL_NAME = "Channel_Name";
    public static final String SEARCH = "Search";
    public static final String LICENSE_ACCEPTED = "isLicenseAccepted";
    public static final String VIDEOS_PER_PAGE = "NumPerPage";
    public static final Boolean DOWNLOAD_THUMBS = new Boolean(true);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response, however please note the question is one year old. :) meaning it's out-dated. I should have closed/deleted it to prevent people from answering an out-dated question. Going to do this soon..

Comment: If this is the correct answer, you should just mark it correct. If somebody searches for this, and you've deleted it that would just suck :)

Comment: Since it's been answered I can not delete it now. :) Actually Richard's answer pointed me to the solution - I easily used `PersistentStore` with `ContentProtectedHashtable` then.